# Angularjs modal and function dont work properly

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I have a function that is called from a modal, the function takes a value and puts it in a text box. The function works when I call from the page but when I call from the modal does not work.

```
$scope.accept = function (id) {

                  console.log($scope.nomco);
                  $scope.NIF = id;
                  //$scope.modalOptions.close();

              };
```

And the button:

```
<button ng-click="accept('prueba');"><strong>Seleccionar</strong></button>
```

Comment: Does the modal have access to the same scope as when you call from the rest of the page? i.e. are you sure that in your modal scope `accept('prueba')` can see `accept`?

Comment: Yes, function responds but "NIF" does not take the value of "id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the example from the ui-bootstrap page.

```
 //main page controller

  angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModal, $log) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

  modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };

  $scope.toggleAnimation = function () {
    $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
  };

});

// Modal controller
//see how the data is being passed from the main controller to the modal controller

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, items) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```